# Trying to search for a string in all the class in Smalltalk VisualWorks?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I am trying to create a small function to search a string in entire application.

I got this code but it won't help much

```
aString := '\\'.
class := DosFileDirectory.
methodsContainingString := class methodDictionary values select: [:method |
    method hasLiteralSuchThat: [:lit |
        (lit isString and: [lit isSymbol not]) and:
            [lit = aString]]].
messageList := methodsContainingString collect: [ :e | MethodReference new setStandardClass: class methodSymbol: e selector ].

SystemNavigation new
    browseMessageList: messageList
    name: 'methods containing string'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the MethodCollector directly (see MethodCollector>>methodsSelect:)

```
| mc pattern |
pattern := '*',searchString,'*'. 
mc := MethodCollector new. 
mc browseSelect: (mc methodsSelect: [:m | pattern match: m getSource]).
```

The MethodCollector already takes care of iterating through methods, no need to do it yourself. The MethodCollector also defines means of combining queries, so you can also limit the query to methods of in certain package.

Answer (score 0):

To search the entire source code, you can do the following

```
searchAll := [ :searchedString |
    (Object withAllSubclasses collect: [ :cls |
        cls methodDictionary values select: [ :method |
            (method getSource findString: searchedString startingAt: 1) > 0
        ]
    ]) inject: #() into: [ :arr :each | arr, each ]
]
```

- `Object withAllSubclasses` will select all classes in the system
- `method getSource findString:startingAt:` will do the matching itself (you can replace it with regexps etc.)
- `#inject:into:` will flatten the array (otherwise it's an array of arrays)

To do the search, evaluate the block:

```
matchedMethods := searchAll value: 'Answer a Paragraph' "(returns a collection of methods containing the string)"
```

Finally, you can inspect the collection, or open it in a browser:

```
MethodCollector new
    openListBrowserOn: (matchedMethods collect: [ :each | each definition ])
    label: 'methods containing "Answer a Paragraph"'
```